# Inner products on abelian groups and general modules

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, modules, abelian-groups

Where can I find a discussion about inner products on something more general than vector spaces, and to which extent should one attempt such a generalization?

My particular interest is in abelian groups (specifically, the representation ring of a finite group, as described [on *MO*](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2808/57127)). The only references in this case seem to be *Distance-Regular Graphs* by Brower, Cohen and Neumaier (1989), [p. 72](https://books.google.fr/books?id=v6brCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA72&dq=inner%20product%20on%20abelian%20group%20-character%20-representation&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false), which does provide a construction for finite groups (contingent on their classification, or so it seems), but no connection to the field case, and *λ-Rings and the Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group* by Knutson (1973), which only concerns itself with the representation ring. (See also [this post](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2013&task=show_msg&msg=3483) on *Ask an Algebraist* about the former book.) I would like to see how it fits with the usual inner products over $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$.

> Seeing as this question appears to have gone largely unnoticed, I have [posted a copy](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261038/) on *MO*.

Comment: This there any context to this? What are you trying to understand? What motivation do you have for generalizing?

Comment: @JMag The representation ring “inner product” $(V,W) = \mathop{\mathrm{dim}} \mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}(V,W)$ that turns into the inner product of characters when tensored with $\mathbf C$. The *MO* link and Knutson reference in the question describe this idea.